# Routes and Embedded View/Controller linking in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, url-routing

Routing in Ember.js is troubling me, and I can't seem to find the "correct" way of doing what I want to do.

I have a route, let's call it #/map, which contains a series of top-level and containers of child views.

Hierarchically, I have a top map_view, which contains 4 additional views: A topbar (which has topbar menu item triggers within it), a sidebar (which has sidebar menu item triggers in it), and two containerViews (a sidebar menu containerView and a topbar menu containerView), which will contain one or more nested views that are programatically inserted on clicking a menu item trigger.

My issue is that while this works, and I can embed all of these views into their various templates, none of them are linking with controllers, and the controller they are picking up is the map_controller (which makes sense as that is the linked outlet controller for the top level view).  Currently I am using a method described [on Ember's github here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1048#issuecomment-32224315), but it seems a little...hacky?

**Here is a JSFiddle showing the problem.  Notice that the controller for `level-one-entry` and `level-two-entry` is the `index_controller`: http://jsfiddle.net/fishbowl/Z94ZY/3/**

Here are some code snippets for what I am doing to get around it:

map.hbs:

```
<section id='map'>
{{view App.SidebarView}}
{{view App.TopbarView}}
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
</section>
```

topbar_view.js:

```
var TopbarView = Em.View.extend({
templateName: 'topbar',
classNames: ['topbar-container'],
init: function() {
    var content = this.get('content'),
            controller = App.TopbarController.create({
                view: this
            });
    this.set('controller', controller);
    this._super();

}
});

module.exports = TopbarView;
```

topbar_controller.js

```
var TopbarController = App.ApplicationController.extend({
content: Ember.computed.alias('view.content'),
trigger: null,
start_date: null,
end_date: null,
travelling: null,
word: 'topbar'
});

module.exports = TopbarController;
```

I'm not doing anything special in the router other than declaring `this.route('map')`.  A further problem i'm having is that whenever I declare `needs: ['some_other_controller']`, I get an error
`<App.TopbarController:ember413> specifies 'needs', but does not have a container. Please ensure this controller was instantiated with a container.`

Am I missing something blindingly obvious about how to go about linking these together.   I'm guessing that i'm using routing incorrectly.  I don't want to change what the URL is, as i'm technically not moving pages, just opening and closing menus on the page, but I don't really understand how else i'm supposed to use the router to achieve this.

**EDIT 2: i've mocked up another jsfiddle of what I could do with outlets and link-to's, but i'm not sure that I want the URL changing (as you'd probably be able to do odd things with the back button etc): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishbowl/HE48J/17/)** - The alternative to this is to set `location: 'none'` in the Router, but I don't really like that option either...

Comment: You shouldn't create controller instance manually like `App.TopbarController.create()`. Try `{{render 'topBar'}}` instead of `{{view App.TopbarView}}`

Comment: When using `{{render 'topBar'}}`, you don't need `init` method in View

Comment: I had used render before, and that's fine for views that are relatively static, but I don't see how I would implement that on a containerView where the views are swapped in and out frequently